# cp overwrite vs rm then cp

Tags: linux, bash, unix

When I try to overwrite a binary file that is currently launched, `cp` fails to overwrite, but it's possible to `rm` it then `cp`. For example:

```
user@poste:~$ cp binaryFile /tmp
user@poste:~$ sudo cp /tmp/binaryFile binaryFile 
[sudo] password for user:
cp: cannot create regular file `binaryFile`: Text file busy
user@poste:~$ sudo rm binaryFile 
user@poste:~$ sudo cp /tmp/binaryFile  binaryFile 
user@poste:~$ file binaryFile 
binaryFile : ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x7ce005d9eb50e2574246b6a881e625802f7e49f2, not stripped
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Interesting little thread, but should be on Unix/Linux.SE IMO.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In the first case, you're trying to overwrite the contents of a file that is *currently running* as a program. Linux does not allow that – if it did, you'd overwrite code right as the OS was executing it; the first difference would crash the program or make it malfunction.

But in the second case, you're not actually changing the old file's contents – you're creating a *new* file in its place, while the old one just loses the filename but keeps its contents untouched.

(Remember that `rm` doesn't *technically* delete files, it just removes directory links – similar to how `ln` adds more links to the same file. Only when a file has no links *and* no open file references, it automatically gets deleted.)

The system references in-use files by their inode, so it doesn't matter that they have the same filename – it's still the *old* file that remains open by the system, and even though it has no links anymore, it will only get deleted once all programs close it.

Comment: Another trick that is often used using the same logic: Open a (temporary) file in your software and delete it immediately, without closing the file first. Your program can still use it any way it wants and when your program closes it (controlled) or forgets to close it (e.g your program crashed without cleanup) it will automatically be removed by the OS. (End of program, no matter how that happened, releases all references to program had to the file.)

Comment: That's also why when you delete some log file of a running process the df command does not return the corrected size until you stop the process

Comment: Is there any way for an external program (with root privilidges) to  find and create a new handle for this dangling inode?  I imagine there are programs that use this as a "security feature" so it's interesting to understand the full story.

Comment: @BenPen: On Linux, yes – use `/proc/*/fd` to access it, and optionally [linkat()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395329/why-does-linkat-require-a-path-name-instead-of-a-file-descriptor) to add a new link to the filesystem.

Comment: Oh, jeez, too easy.  I forgot about /proc/*/fd.  It's interesting that the file system has to be encoded inside of /proc, would you have to derive that somehow to create the hardlink?

Comment: @BenPen and grawity: Actually, you can't link an inode back into the directory structure if it has zero links, [even with `linkat()`, for security reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4174216/224132).  (Exception to this rule: unless it was created with `open(O_TMPFILE)` so it *started* with zero links.)  If you try, `linkat()` returns ENOENT, even as root.  See my answer on that question for a perl script to actually run `linkat` and prove that it doesn't work, even as root :/